# Laravel 5.8. Как использовать переменную .env файла в webpack.mix.js

Tags: laravel, webpack, .env

В файле .env я сделал следующее:

APP_ENV=production

MIX_APP_ENV="${APP_ENV}"

В файле webpack.mix.js:

const APP_ENV = process.env.MIX_APP_ENV;

Используя оператор if else, я проверил, что ничего не было присвоено переменной APP_ENV. Мне нужно сделать следующее - в зависимости от среды, скомпилировать файлы sass и js в определенную папку.

Я пытаюсь сделать следующее, но ничего не работает:

```
const APP_ENV = process.env.MIX_APP_ENV;

if (APP_ENV == 'dev' || APP_ENV == 'production') {
    mix
        .js('resources/js/app.js', 'js')
        .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'css')
        .version();
} else {
    mix
        .setPublicPath('public/build')
        .setResourceRoot('/build/')
        .js('resources/js/app.js', 'js')
        .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'css')
        .version();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Не нужно было создавать промежуточную переменную MIX_APP_ENV в .env файле. 
Следующий код рабочий:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const env = process.env.APP_ENV;
```